# Integration with exponential

Tags: calculus, integration

With solving a problem in probability, I find an integral not sure how to do it.

$\int_{|y|}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2x}e^{-x}dx$

Because when I use the theorem $\int f(x)g'(x)=f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)$ .i.e.$\int_{|y|}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2x}e^{-x}=-\frac{1}{2x}e^{-x}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{|y|}^{\infty}(-x^{-2}e^{-x})dx$

But how to continue from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't integrate it in terms of elementary functions, so we give it a name.  This is $E_1(|y|)$, the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) divided by $2$

Comment: Alternatively, you can express the result as an (upper) incomplete gamma function: $\Gamma(0,|y|)/2$. This might be a more natural way of putting it, considering that OP encountered the integral in the context of probabilities...

Comment: The problem with probability that the OP wants to solve is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/70705/15941) and the marginal density that the OP is asking about here (without naming it as such) is not really needed to answer the question that he really wants to solve.